# How to set the scroll height dynamically?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I have a div which has a height of 1200px and a width of the browser window. Just below that div I have another div with a height of 1000px. Now at the moment when scrolling down you will be able to scroll until the end of the second div. What I would like is to set the scroll height, so for example I would like to say you should only be able to scroll for 1200px. That way my second div would not be visible to the visitor. Is there some way to achieve this with JQuery?

**I uploaded a picture emphasizing my problem:**

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. Why don't you just hide the div?

Comment: Oh and for your question, yes it is possible, but as usual: what have you tried?

Comment: Because I want to hide some stuff with a div on top of it. And since the width of the page depends on the width of the browser window (the page will zoom out), when you change the width to a small size you will be able to see the content which is below 1200px.

Comment: @romainberger Didn't try anything as I don't really know how to start. I didn't find anything about this particular problem or about setting the scroll height.

Comment: If content should not be seen by user, why not simply set `style="display:none"` to a div that should not be visible?

Comment: That's not possible due to this reason: I have multiple circles (divs with round borders) and I want only half of the circles to be seen. So I put a div on top of it.

Comment: Change css so it will be shown as a half of a circle?  http://jsfiddle.net/SLwL3/ See different classes. Circle and halfcircle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle `window.onscroll`, prevent the event from propagating if the user has scrolled too far and send them back to where they're meant to be looking:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wYng7/)

```
window.onscroll = function (e) {
    var maxViewableHeight = 1400;
    if (document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight > maxViewableHeight) {
    console.log(document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight);
        e.preventDefault;
        document.body.scrollTop = maxViewableHeight - window.innerHeight;
        return false;
    }
}
```

### Update

Here is a more cross-browser friendly version, tested in Chrome 25, Firefox 19, IE10/IE9, Safari 5, Opera 12. In IE, Safari and Opera it bounces a bit. Particularly Opera due to its fancy smooth scrolling, makes me appreciate Firefox more because it has smooth scrolling and was perfect.

```
window.onscroll = function (e) {
    var maxViewableHeight = 1400,
        scrollTop = getScrollTop();
    if (scrollTop + window.innerHeight > maxViewableHeight) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.scrollTo(0, maxViewableHeight - window.innerHeight);
        return false;
    }
}

function getScrollTop() {
    if (typeof window.pageYOffset !== 'undefined') {
        return window.pageYOffset;
    }
    var body = document.body,
        docElement = document.documentElement;
    docElement = (docElement.clientHeight) ? docElement : body;
    return docElement.scrollTop;
}
```

Comment: Any idea why this does neither seem to work in IE nor in Firefox?

Comment: Perfect, thank you alot for your efforts! Changing the size of the scrollbar is probably not possible, is it? So that the user doesn't see that the page is actually still longer.

Comment: No you can't change the size of the scrollbar. However that would basically achieve the same effect as placing the "hidden stuff" in a `<div>` and hiding that `<div>` with JavaScript.